# What is the rate of convergence of the argmins of a sequence of uniformly convergent strictly convex functions?

Tags: convergence-divergence, convex-analysis, uniform-convergence, rate-of-convergence

From Theorem 2.1 and 2.2 in Kanniappan (1983) "Uniform convergence of convex optimization problems", if a sequence of strictly convex functions $f_n$  uniformly converge to a strictly convex function $f$, then the sequence of solutions $x_n$ of $f_n$ converge to the unique solution $x_0$ of $f$.

Now, if you know that $||f_n-f||=o(g(n))$, is it true that $||x_n-x_0||=o(g(n))$?

And, if you know that $||f_n-f||=O(g(n))$ what could you say about $||x_n-x_0||$?

$O$ and $o$ are big and little O respectively.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it is not clear which reference you are citing

Comment: It is "Uniform convergence of convex optimization problems" Kaniappan 1983